# How to perform role based authorization without identity framework?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-6.0

I am looking at a web api which performs authentication/authorization without the identity framework.

The program.cs file has got the authentication configured as follows:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddJwtBearer(options => ....
```

The login controller action sets a JWT token with the user's login name and returns it to the caller. Every other controller action has either the [Authorize] or [AllowAnonymous] attribute to control access.

I am tasked to add role based authorization to this web api. For example so that I can use [Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")] for admin controller actions. In the database user table I have created the Role column as a placeholder for the user's role; thus performing role based authorization.

I am looking at this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/roles?view=aspnetcore-6.0 - but this is about role based authorization when using identity. But I am not using identity framework.

A solution I am thinking is - during login, write the role into the JWT token and then code an attribute for each role (which is to be applied to respective controller actions) such that it compares the role in the JWT token.

Is role based authorization dependent on .net identity? Or can I simply set the value of Role or Claim into the JWT token (during login) and via the usual `[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]` automatically perform role based authorization, is this supported? Any simple example or reference on this will be helpful.

Comment: It is not based on identity, no. If you have the appropriate claims it should just work.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.claims.claimtypes.role?view=net-6.0 -- if nobody has answered in the morning I'll provide an answer.

Comment: So in login controller when I generate the JWT token, do I simply set the `Role` or do I set the Role inside of a Claim? I have read that an identity can have claims, and also that a role can have claims.

Comment: A role is a specific type or claim. A logged in user is represented by an identity, which has the claims.

Comment: Can you point me to an article on this topic, will be very helpful please. I want to understand this - that a user can have claims and roles, and a role can have claims, and what you say is a user (identity) can have claims, but I know it can also have roles which can have claims, I need clarity on this topic.

Comment: In your above comment `A role is a specific type or claim.` I believe you wanted to say OF CLAIM?

Comment: I did indeed mean to say of.

Comment: the solution you are thinking is correct if you are managing user and roles in your application without using identity framework

Comment: @CodingMytra - as I said in my question I am using `builder.Services.AddAuthentication`, but I am not using `builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>( ... )
    .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()` - so does this mean I am using Identity or not ?

Comment: not using identity. but then you have to somehow manage your role and users in your application

Comment: The highest voted answer seems to indicate that just entering the Role in the JWT will work. I assume by `somehow manage` you mean the database storage of users/role? If so then yes I have a custom users table

Comment: then it is easy to use ans given by Ruikai.

Answer (score 3):

when you generate the token ,add the "role"claim

```
var claims = new Claim[]
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "Jeffcky"),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role,"Administrator")
            };
var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("........"));

            var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
              issuer: "......",
              audience: "......",
              claims: claims,
              notBefore: DateTime.Now,
              expires: DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5),
              signingCredentials: new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256)
            );
var token=new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
```

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if I understand your question wrong, but do you want to implement a custom provider to authenticate via your API?

Here I've implemented a custom provider that validates user/pass with data stored in Ontraport web service.

https://github.com/mysteryx93/OntraportApi.NET/tree/master/OntraportApi.IdentityCore

Comment: There is no existing or future plan to use the identity framework

Comment: ok I'm not sure whether role-based authentication works separately from it... perhaps a deeper layer of abstraction, or an older way of doing it before Identity Framework got released? Let's see what others have to say.